# How to display a Json data with object name starting with numbers

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, weatherstack

```
     "current": {
            "observation_time": "03:38 PM",
            "temperature": 18,
            "weather_code": 113,
            "weather_icons": [
                "https://assets.weatherstack.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            ],
            "weather_descriptions": [
                "Sunny"
            ],
            "wind_speed": 0,
            "wind_degree": 345,
            "wind_dir": "NNW",
            "pressure": 1011,
            "precip": 0,
            "humidity": 58,
            "cloudcover": 0,
            "feelslike": 18,
            "uv_index": 5,
            "visibility": 16
        },
        "forecast": {
            "2019-09-07": {
                "date": "2019-09-07",
                "date_epoch": 1567814400,
                "astro": {
                    "sunrise": "06:28 AM",
                    "sunset": "07:19 PM",
                    "moonrise": "03:33 PM",
                    "moonset": "12:17 AM",
                    "moon_phase": "First Quarter",
                    "moon_illumination": 54
                },
                "mintemp": 17,
                "maxtemp": 25,
                "avgtemp": 21,
                "totalsnow": 0,
                "sunhour": 10.3,
                "uv_index": 5,

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I want to display sunrise and sunset and also the sunhour under the forecast object, So far i have tried {forecast["2019-09-07"].astro.sunrise} but it's still not working, Please what how else do i call it from the api?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use ramda path for it https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path

```
path(['2019-09-07', 'astro', 'sunrise'])(forecast)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did

```
{country.forecast?.["2022-11-11"]?.astro?.sunrise}
```

and it **worked**, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
{forecast['2019-09-07'].astro.sunrise}
```

Thanks